# FirebaseError auth/login-blocked in Nuxt 3 app deployed to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 app using Firebase Authentication that is deployed to Firebase Hosting. When trying to sign in, I am getting the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/login-blocked).
```

In the browser console, I see the following error:

```
POST https://nuxt-vuefire-2576f.web.app/api/__session 404
```

It seems the __session endpoint used by Firebase Auth is returning a 404.

I have:

- Enabled the domain in the Firebase console
- Enabled IAM Service Account Credentials API

**The auth works locally but not when deployed.**

I noticed some other folks have reported this issue here (but no resolution yet):
https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/1408

Here is a [live demo](https://nuxt-vuefire-2576f.web.app/) showing the issue.

Inspect the browser console and you'll see the api session error. Furthermore, try to login and you'll see the login issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I had to remove the VueFire package. Problem went away.

Comment: More details on this answer can help. I'm using nuxt-vuefire but I'm getting the same issue. Didn't directly install vuefire.

Comment: the latest version of vuefire fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

its most likely because you have not passed GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT environment variables while running the production mode using node. Production mode does not read the .env file, you need to export this variable on your environment manually.

Also make sure you do not have any server middlewares rejecting this route.